# How to create a user group in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a user group through API, when I created a view to create a group, it shows error like this.

> Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields'
> attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated
> since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields =
> '**all**' to the GroupSerializer serializer

MySerializer

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        field = '__all__'
```

MyView

```
class GroupView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, tenant, format=None):
        tenant = get_tenant(tenant)
        serializer = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, safe=False)
```

Comment: You have typo in class Meta of GroupSerializer, field instead of fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `field` to `fields` as shown on Django docs

```
class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```